# Are the Sky Map APIs available?

Tags: android

I'm looking to build an application similar to Google Sky Map, and was wondering if it was possible to hook into any of the APIs it uses. If so, which ones? If not, how else can it be done?

From what i've read so far, I can do a search via an intent for any the objects in Google's sky map db.. but i'd like to have my own db of satellites going around the earth, and be able to track those, get reminders on fly-overs and so-on.. so i'd like to build this app, but i just need a jumping off point.

Thanks!